# Alternative of pd.NamedAgg to a code compliant with pandas 0.24.2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

When I'm trying to run my code, I'm facing the error:
`AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'NamedAgg'` . Can someone help me with the alternative of this?. Thanks
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_excel('testingfile.xlsx')
df_grouped = df.groupby(['result_by', 'variable']).agg(count_col=pd.NamedAgg(column='variable', aggfunc="count"))
df1=df_grouped.reset_index()
subsetDataFrame = df1[df1['result_by'].isin(['mango', 'apple','guava','berry']) ]
final_result=subsetDataFrame.pivot(index='variable',columns='result_by' ,values='count_col').fillna('-')
final_result
```

Comment: `NamedAgg` allows you to name the aggregated column after aggregating. So you can simply omit this command, do a simple aggregation, then rename the column afterwards.

Comment: sorry, i've not understood, can you please share a sample code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in comment, you can do this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('testingfile.xlsx')
df_grouped = df.groupby(['result_by', 'variable']).agg({'variable':"count"}).rename(column={'variable':'count_col'})
```

The rest of the code can be the same.

Anyway your problem can be solved if you upgrade your pandas to newer (0.25+) version.